# Is the "very low quality" question flag new?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

I've noticed that the "very low quality" flag has started showing up on some questions, instead of just answers:

[image: very low quality question flag image]

If I'd seen this before, this would probably have been a great help in flagging questions with bad formatting problems.

Is it new, or have I just been overlooking it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by [Taryn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164200/taryn) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> **If a question has a score of <= 0, it's less than 7 days old, and it's not currently in review (Triage or Close)**, then a user will be presented with an option to flag it as 'very low quality'. This flag will send the questions into Triage on Stack Overflow or the Low Quality Review queue elsewhere.
>   -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659/165483

You probably didn't see this flag earlier on questions as those you tried to flag didn't qualify for VLQ flagging.

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: What's odd is that the search results didn't show anything about the "very low quality" flag not showing up. All they were about pretty much summed up to "why is my question/answer very low quality".

Comment: @JL2210 Google "site:meta.stackoverflow.com very low quality flag not showing up". The built-in search engine here sometimes suck.